# Perl how to insert element between an array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have 4 arrays (14,12),(13,12),(13,11),(14,13,11). So i have 4 unique elements ie 11,12,13,14 from all 4 arrays. Now i need to make a new array containing these 4 elements.
Condition, for each of the given 4 array, new array should follow condition that array element(i) should occur before element(i+1) and so on.
My New array should be either(14,13,11,12) or (14,13,12,11). I want both these arrays.

Explanation:
in(14,13,12,11)

```
14 comes before 12 so arr1 condition met.
13 comes before 12 so arr2 condition met
13 comes before 11 so arr 3 condition met
14 comes before 13 and 13 comes before 11, so arr 4 condition met.
```

I am thinking of starting my new array as (14,12) ie arr1 elements and then check next array for any matching elements, but it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) based on [partial orderings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). Unix has a built-in called `tsort` that should do what you want.

If you want your own Perl implementation, how about something like this?

```
my @A = (
    [14, 12],
    [13,12],
    [13,11],
    [14,13,11]
);

my @final;
my %seen;
my $c;
do{
    $c = 0;
    foreach my $a (@A){
       my $elt = shift @$a;
       next if ! defined $elt || $seen{$elt}++;
       push( @final, $elt );
       $c++;
    }
}while( $c );

print join(',', @final) . "\n";
```